# Django model relationship - Fitness App

Tags: python, django-models

Currently my models are:

```
class Workout(models.Model):    
    date = models.DateField()
    routine = models.ForeignKey('Routine')
    def __str__(self):
         return '%s' % self.date

class Routine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField('Exercise')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

 class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want the user to be able to create a new entry specified by a date(Workout). They can also create routines(Routine), associated with the date and filled with different exercises(Exercise) which they can also create.

Here is the part I can't figure out.

I want the user, when adding a new exercise, to be able to choose whether it is a strength exercise or cardio exercise. Strength exercises will have fields like: #of sets, reps, and weight. Where as carido will have fields like length and speed.

I am unclear on how to relate the two types of exercises to the Exercise class.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way of doing this, is to create a [generic relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations), such as:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    info = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class StrengthExercise(models.Model):
    sets, reps, weight = (...)

class CardioExercise(models.Model):
    length, speed = (...)
```

Example use:

```
>>> from app_name.models import Exercise, CardioExercise
>>> exercise_info = CardioExercise.objects.create(length=600, speed=50)
>>> exercise = Exercise(name="cardio_exercise_1", info=exercise_info)
>>> exercise.save()
>>> exercise.info.length
600
>>> exercise.info.__class__.__name__
'CardioExercise'
```

*OBS: Make sure you have `'django.contrib.contenttypes'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` (enabled by default).*